# HTML included side menu interferes with page spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a page with a lightbox gallery and an included menu down the side. When the menu is included it creates a large space between  the gallery rows that I can't remove which goes away when the menu is removed.

```
<tr>
    <td rowspan="10" id="body-text-other">
        <span style="float:left;"><?php include("includes/header-store.html") ?></span>
        <span style="width: 100px;"><?php include("includes_releasing/store_menu.html") ?></span>

    <div>
        <p id="body-text-lrg">Pledge Cards</p>


                    <div class="imageRow">
                    <div class="single">
                        <a href="images/art/gallery/Arise.png" rel="lightbox[ceinwen]"><img src="images/art/gallery/Arise-thumbnail.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single">
                        <a href="images/art/gallery/Reluctance.png" rel="lightbox[ceinwen]"><img src="images/art/gallery/Reluctance-thumbnail.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>  
                 </div>

                 <div class="imageRow">
                    <div class="single">
                        <a href="images/art/gallery/Correlation.png" rel="lightbox[ceinwen]"><img src="images/art/gallery/Correlation-thumbnail.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single">
                        <a href="images/art/gallery/Dissidence.png" rel="lightbox[ceinwen]"><img src="images/art/gallery/Dissidence-thumbnail.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @user and welcome to SO. In your code sample, you've got incomplete tags, so it's hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the quick response. I'm a bit of a novice and I was handed a half completed site to finish. I suspect the original builder wasn't much more informed than me. I can't see anything missing from the sample, could you let me know what you need to help?

Thanks

Comment: People here are happy to help if you show some evidence of your effort.  Right now, it looks like you've dumped a bunch of markup here and are asking people to fix it for you.  If you're seriously stuck, try reading up on HTML tags (like `<tr>`) and debugging your markup, for starters. Then, you'll be able to pinpoint where your "large space" is coming from, or post here with a complete code sample.  You'll get a better response, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. If you could provide more sample code we can take a better look at it. The problem may be that you are using tables and the default padding/margin are making it bigger.

If you could provide a JSFiddle we can help more.

Thanks and goodluck.
http://jsfiddle.net/